# liquid - unless for.loop always seems to be last

Tags: ruby, shopify, liquid

Consider this below:

```
{% for variant in product.variants %}
    {{ forloop.index }}<br>
    {{ unless forloop.last }}LAST<br>{{ endunless }}
{% endfor %}
```

According to the [shopify docs](https://shopify.dev/docs/themes/liquid/reference/objects/for-loops#forloop-last):

> Returns true if it's the last iteration of the for loop. Returns false
>   if it is not the last iteration.

The output of the code above is: (for 3 variants)

```
1
LAST
2
LAST
3
LAST
```

Why? Is the variant object different from the others in context of `forloop.last`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have delimited your `unless` query with double curly brace delimiters rather than curly brace percentage delimiters. As such, they don't form a conditional scope around the literal value `LAST` which is thus always added (ignoring the conditional).

If you use the correct brace style for conditions, it should work correctly:

```
{% for variant in product.variants %}
    {{ forloop.index }}<br>
    {% unless forloop.last %}LAST<br>{% endunless %}
{% endfor %}
```

See [the documentation](https://shopify.dev/api/liquid#liquid-syntax) for details.

Comment: – "See the documentation for details" – according to the docs, the only difference seem to be output vs. no output :-)